# Add network service

Tags: service, wix, installation, driver

I have a kernel service driver , i want to install it with an installer .
I use Wix that already copy files in driver store but i still need to add the service to the nerwork  manualy (in local area connection properties)
How can i do this in wix or in javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good example in WinDDK  : src\network\config\bindview

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a custom action to do this.  You can choose between managed ( C# / DTF ) and unmanaged ( C++ ) and I'm guessing you'll need unmanaged.  WiX has a C++ Custom Action project to help you get started.

Comment: What sould i do in my CustomAction ? i need an example showing how to add a network service.

Comment: I don't know since I've never needed to do this.  I do know though that Windows Installer doesn't support this so you will need a CA.  You'll have to research the Win32 API to understand what calls to make to programatically execute what you are doing interactively by hand.

BTW, I know InstallShield integrates with DIFx ( Driver Installation Framework ) so you might want to look at that also to see if it can do what you need so you possibly don't have to write your own custom actions.   I've only ever used DIFx once and never with WiX but it should be possible.